# Why does ReadFileEx on a USBPRINT device fail with ERROR_GEN_FAILURE?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, printing, usb

When calling `ReadFileEx` on a handle to a USBPRINT device on Windows, it sometimes returns `ERROR_GEN_FAILURE`. This happens randomly and I can only get the device to respond again if I physically unplug the device and plug it back in.

Specifically, I am using a USB-to-Parallel adapter with a Prolific PL2305 chip connected to an Epson TM-U29P slip printer.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there is a grounding screw on the back of the TM-U295P that must be wired directly to ground. I initially ignored this because I figured the power supply was grounded and so was the USB adapter, but I guess I was wrong. Connecting a ground wire fixed the spurious I/O failures.